# Why don't I pass any parameters to a function within map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How come we do not have to pass an argument to `function b` 
in the code below? Is it just because we are using map method of type Array? Or is there anywhere else that we can use a function just like this in 
JavaScript?

Can someone give a very clean and through explanation?

Code:

```
/* we have an array a*/
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
/*we define a function called b to process a single element*/
const b = function(x){do something here};
/*I noticed that if we want to use function b to take care with the 
elements in array a. we just need to do the following.*/
a.map(b);
```

Comment: Consider the expression `a.map(function (x) { return b(x); })`, then observe that `function(x) { return b(x); }` is equivalent to `b`.

Comment: The current title does not really fit the question. Please consider changing the title, as you are not actually asking *how* to pass parameters, but *why no* parameters are being (explicitly) passed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Functions are first class citizens in Javascript, which is just a fancy way of saying they can be passed around as variables and arguments.

What you are doing when you call

```
a.map(b);
```

Is essentially calling

```
[
  b('a'),
  b('b'),
  b('c')
]
```

The array function [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) just calls the given function (in your case `b`), with each argument in the array, and puts the output in a new array. So there are arguments being passed to `b`, it's just that `map` is doing it behind the scenes for you.

As for your other questions, there are plenty of cases where you'll pass a function as an argument without calling it first. Another common function is the Array object's [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const out = a.reduce(function (accumulator, val) {
  return accumulator + ' - ' + val;
}
// out: 'a - b - c'
```

Also a lot of functions take callbacks, that are called when some kind of asynchronous task is completed. For instance. `setTimeout`, will call a given function after the elapsed time.

```
setTimeout(function (){
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }, 1000
);
// Will print "Hello World!" to console after waiting 1 second (1000 milliseconds).
```

And you can easily write your function to take another function as an argument too! Just call the function you've passed in as you would any other function.

```
// A really basic example
// More or less the same as [0, 1, 2].map(...)
function callThreeTimes(f) {
  return [
    f(0),
    f(1),
    f(2)
  ]
}

// My function here returns the square of a given value
function square(val) { return val * val }

const out = callThreeTimes(square);
// out: [0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man. I understand what you have explained. My actual question is why we don’t need pass any argument to b here? Like a.map(b(x))

Comment: Because `map` is providing the arguments for you. Calling `b('a')`, then `b('b')`, then `b('c')`.

Comment: @red_Coder Have another look at the `callThreeTimes` function. There you see explicitly where the parameter comes from.

Answer (score 7):

You don't pass arguments to `b` because **you're not calling it**.  You're passing *the function itself* as a value.

The use of `map` here is irrelevant; you can see what's happening directly:

```
const a = function(x) { alert(`called with ${x}`); };

// The function is NOT called here; it's just being assigned,
// like any other kind of value.  This causes "b" to become
// another name for "a".
// This is NOT the same as a(), which would call the function
// with undefined as the argument.
const b = a;

// Now we call it, and the alert happens here
b(5);
```

Passing a function to another function works the same way, since it's just another form of assignment.

This is useful because you can tell other code *how* to do something even if you yourself don't know *what* the arguments are.  In the particular case of `map`, it loops over the array for you and calls the function once for each element.  You don't *want* to be calling the function you pass to `map`, because the entire purpose of `map` is to call the function for you.

Answer (score 4):

map accepts function as a parameter and executes provided function for every element of an array.
Here you are passing function **b** as a parameter to map, hence map executes function **b** for every elements of array **a**.
So you do not need to pass arguments to function **b** here, map will take care of this.

Comment: This is the answer I wanted! So in JavaScript, is there any other built in method working like this? And can we write any functions like map for array? Thanks!

Comment: yes, there are some other built in functions in javascript ex. forEach, filter etc, the only difference is the way they process or check for output of call back functions

Answer (score 2):

You probably heard that functions are first class citizens in javascript.
If you look at the docs from [MDN map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) you will notice that the map function accepts a callback with up to 3 arguments first one being `currentValue`

So let's break it down. A very explicit example of doing a map over the array above would be this one

```
 a.map(function(currentValue, index, array){
   // here you can access the 3 parameters from the function declaration
 });
```

This function is called on each iteration of the array. Since functions are very flexible in javascript, you could only declare 1 parameter or even none if you want to.

```
a.map(function(currentValue){
   // we need only the current value
});
```

> Every function in JavaScript is a Function object. [Source here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description)

This means that every function is just a reference in the memory, meaning it can be specified either directly as an anonymous function (which is our case above), or declared before like this

```
   function b(currentValue){
     // this will be called on each item in the array
   };

   a.map(b)
```

This piece of code iterates over each element in the array and calls the reference we passed it (function b). It actually calls it with all the 3 parameters from the documentation.

```
  [
    b('a',0,a),
    b('b',1,a),
    b('c',1,a)
  ]
```

But since our `function b` only declared one, we can access the value only.
The other arguments are stored in the so-called [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Take from here **Every function in JavaScript is a Function object** which makes every function a reference to a certain memory location which in the end leaves us with a lot of flexibility of passing the function as a parameter however we want to (explicit via an anonymous function, or implicit via a function declaration (reference) )

Comment: thanks for your explanation,

Now I understand why `["a", "b", "c"].map(console.log)` return`a 0 [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
b 1 [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
c 2 [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`

Answer (score 1):

> how come we do not have to pass argument to function b here?

Simply because as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map), `map` calls the `b` with **3** **implicitly**.

> **callbackfn is called with three arguments**: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the object being traversed

For each *element in the array*, *callback function* is invoked with these *three arguments*

- **value** of the element (`a`, `b` and `c` in your case)
- **index** of the element
- `b` itself (object being traversed).

Answer (score 1):

> Why there are no parenthesis?

When you are passing a function as an argument to the sort method it doesnt have parentheses after the function name. This is because the function is not supposed to be called right then and there but rather the map method to have a reference to this function so that it can call it as needed while it's trying to map the array.

> Why it does not  take any arguments?

Now we know that map will be calling this callback function accordingly, so when map calls it it implicitly passes the arguments to it while calling it.

For example if this would be callback of sort then the argument passed will be current element and next element. If this is a callback for map then the arguments will be current value, index, array.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are just another type of object.

Calling a function without arguments is done as follows. This will always execute the function and return the function's return value.

```
var returnValue = b();
```

Removing the parenthesis will instead treat the function itself as a variable, that can be passed around in other variables, arguments etc.

```
var myFunction = b;
```

At any point such adding parenthesis to the "function variable" will execute the function it refers to and return the return value.

```
var returnValue = myFunction();
var sameReturnValue = b();
```

So map() accepts one argument, which is of type function (no parenthesis). It will then call this function (parenthesis) for each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow you will find how to use the map function:

*first Methode*

```
incrementByOne = function (element) {
  return element + 1;
}
myArray = [1,2,3,4];
myArray.map(incrementByOne); // returns [2,3,4,5]
```

*Seconde methode*

```
myArray = [0,1,2,3];
myArray.map(function (element) {
  return element + 1;
}); // returns [1,2,3,4]
```

*Third Methode*

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4];
myArray.map(element => {
  return element + 1;
});
```